# Application run well from eclipse, but fails to start, when it is deployed manually

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven-2, tomcat, maven

I have web application using SpringFramework3.0.3.RELEASE, developed in Eclipse with m2eclipse plugin and deployed into Tomcat6.0.26. I can run it from Eclipse, but when copy target WAR int same tomcat instance ( removing WTP webapp first ) and restart I see following exception:

```
Sep 14, 2010 5:54:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Sep 14, 2010 5:54:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'onboardSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'customListener' while setting bean property 'eventListeners' with key [TypedStringValue: value [pre-insert], target type [null]]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customListener' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.log4j.LogManager
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedMap(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:383)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:161)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1317)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:557)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:905)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:740)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customListener' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.log4j.LogManager
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:901)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
 ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.log4j.LogManager
 at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:117)
 at com.mycompany.listener.CustomHibernateListener.<clinit>(CustomHibernateListener.java:69)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
 at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:71)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:948)
 ... 49 more
Sep 14, 2010 5:54:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

I've checked and the only org.apache.log4j.Logger.class file is inside log4j-1.2.14.jar of my application. LogManager present in same package, but it is reported as missed. My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
 <artifactId>mainProject</artifactId>
 <version>1.1.8</version>
 <packaging>war</packaging>

 <build>
  <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>  
  <plugins>           
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <webXml>WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
     <webResources>
      <resource> 
       <directory>src</directory>
       <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath> 
       <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*.java</exclude> 
       </excludes> 
      </resource>
     </webResources>
     <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>     

   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>    
   </plugin>

  </plugins>
 </build>
 <repositories>..</repositories>

 <dependencies>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
   <type>jar</type>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.1</version>
   <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Hibernate, Hibernate Search and dependencies -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
   <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
   <version>2.9.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javassist</groupId>
   <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
   <version>3.8.0.GA</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
   <version>3.5.0-Final</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Spring Framework, Spring Security and dependencies -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
   <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>   
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
   <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
   <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>  

  <!-- JUnit, JSFUnit and etc. -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.jsfunit</groupId>
   <artifactId>jboss-jsfunit-core</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
  </dependency>

  <!--  JSF -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.2-FCS</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.2-FCS</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- PrimeFaces and dependencies -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
   <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.RC1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.1</version>
   <type>jar</type>
   <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Sintecmedia infrastructure -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
   <artifactId>rc-infra</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>

 </dependencies>

</project>
```

Another pom.xml from infra project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.mycompany/groupId>
 <artifactId>rc-infra</artifactId>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <version>1.2</version>
 <name>infra</name>
 <description>Spring-Hibernate Infrastructure</description>

 <repositories>..</repositories>

 <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>

            <!-- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/clean-mojo.html -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <!-- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>                 
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <id>attach-sources</id>
         <goals>
           <goal>jar</goal>
         </goals>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <workspace>${eclipse.workspace.dir}</workspace>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.7</version>
             <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${eclipse.workspace.dir}/doc</outputDirectory>
              <sourcePath>${eclipse.workspace.dir}/src/main/java</sourcePath>
             </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

     <dependency>
         <groupId>log4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
         <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>

  <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->
        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
         <version>3.5.1-Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring dependencies -->               
        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>                     
        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Is anybody know what is the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pascal's answer contains a link to useful 'Logging Dependencies in Spring' article. It describes how to override old commons-logging jar and to use slf4j or log4j. The problem was that log4j conflicted with commons-logging. Excluding it from maven dependencies of spring-context, solved the issue. However, I still don't understand why the issue was with manual deploy only and doesn't happened if the webapp is run from Eclipse?

Comment: Sorry about wrong report the problem does not disappear, the exception message just move from console to log file.

Answer (score 2):

```
NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.log4j.LogManager
```

This trace indicates a problem in the `static` initialization block of `org.apache.log4j.LogManager`.

I don't have the full explanation but I would start by doing some clean up in your dependencies, they are a bit messy:

- Why do you have several versions of Hibernate JARs (3.5.0-Final and 3.5.1-Final). You should make them converge.
- Hibernate uses SLF4J, why don't you have any binding for log4j?
- Spring uses commons-logging, I would configure it to use SLF4J also to **avoid any conflicts and potential classloading problems**. See [Logging Dependencies in Spring](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/04/logging-dependencies-in-spring/) for full explanations.

The last point is IMO the most important.

Comment: Thank you for answer CustomHibernateListener saves audit trails and check user permissions to action performed. It declared in my applicationContext.xml, inside sessionFactory bean:

Comment: class="com.sintecmedia.listener.CustomHibernateListener" / -->

As you can see, I've already commented it after the issue is appeared, but now I have the same exception from other classes.
Maven2 should bring to project the dependencies for Spring, if I define Spring as dependency in pom.xml. However I know that it happens, only if all dependencies are defined in pom.xml of spring jars and mistake can occur there. So, I already tried to add org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.1 and org:slf4j-log4j12:1.6.1, since I've use it in other project that works fine. It didn't help.

Comment: You are right, hibernate jars versions is not convergent. However, I've just fixed it and it didn't help.

Comment: I read 'Logging Dependencies in Spring'. Now I understand why slf4j is not included - its optional. But I see that recommended way is to exclude commons-logging, if you use slf4j and log4j. I just done it and it solves my issue

Comment: I still don't undersand why the issue was with manual deploy only and doesn't happened if the webapp is run from Eclipse?

Comment: @Igor Eclipse "builds" some kind of artificial classpath, you can get different behaviors inside and outside Eclipse (as you experimented).

Answer (score 0):

Is the log4j property file on your app classpath? LogManager might use it as a static resource and doesn't initalize if it is missing.

Comment: I don't think this is the cause, not providing a `log4j.properties` doesn't break an application.

Comment: Yes it exists in WEB-INF/classes/ of my application. Morever, the exception reported is NoClassDefFoundError